# How to create an array of object from another array of object with properties

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
const array = [
 {id: 'firstId'},
 {id: 'SecondId'},
 {id: 'ThirdId'}
]
```

I want to reach this result:

```
array = [
{firstId: null},
{SecondId: null},
{ThirdId: null}
]
```

so I tried:

```
array.map([key,value] => {key:value});
```

but I got an array of undefined

Comment: `[key,value] => {key:value}` is not a valid function, what did you actually try to get an array of undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be to do something like:

```js
const array = [
  {id: 'firstId'},
  {id: 'SecondId'},
  {id: 'ThirdId'}
];

const res = array.map( (obj) => ({ [obj.id]: null }) );

console.log(res);
```

Note the parentheses around the arrow function arguments and the parentheses around the curly braces to indicate that the curly braces do not form a block for the function body.